# O(1) Event Publish to N Subscribers

Tags: algorithm, programming-languages, operating-system, complexity-theory, publish-subscribe

Are there any data structures/languages/algorithms/operating systems/etc that enable o(1) event/data publishing to n items? Typically when one sees pubsub implemented it involves traversing through a list of subscribers and firing functions on them.

Is there any platform/language that enables a more instantaneous notification to n items? At the OS level even does there exist any means to make this happen?

I'm inclined to believe its not possible, but i have a limited knowledge of OS/hardware and am wondering if there's something "under the hood" that could enable this.

**My Reason for Asking**

I know this is a bit "out there"-- but having read a bit about [brain cells/neurons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuron), and the fact that a neuron via an electrical charge can send electricity/information through its axon to n receivers, it would make sense to me that this could be mimicked in order to provide o(1) pub to n subscribers at the hardware level, with an OS scheduling it etc.

So i was wondering if that happens anywhere in modern hardware/OSes in one form or another, and especially if its something that can be hooked into with custom callbacks.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "notification".  If you have N subscribers that have each registered a callback, then there are N callbacks to call, and that takes O(N) time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do O(log(n)) notification by having the subscribers publish as well: publisher notifies 2 subscribers, who each notify 2 subscribers, who each notify 2 subscribers, etc.

You can do O(1) "notification", but it involves the subscribers polling and is probably not what you're after. The publisher writes to a shared array, and the subscribers poll on array[i]; when the publisher writes to array[i], the subscribers read the data, and then poll on array[i+1], etc. You can also have the subscribers notify the publisher when they've read array[i] so that the publisher can free the data at array[i] when it has received notifications from all subscribers - this lets you use a circular buffer instead of a continually-growing array. (You can have the subscribers block on array[i] instead of polling on it, but then you're back to having the publisher callback for each subscriber to end its blocking.)

Comment: +1 for the second idea. The first is still O(n) - there are still n publishes happening.

Comment: Depends on how many threads the processor can run at once - in the ideal case that the processor can run all N subscribers concurrently. Unfortunately this probably isn't going to be the case unless you only have a few subscribers (in which case you might as well have the publisher notify each subscriber instead of having the subscribers poll on a shared array) or unless the subscribers are running on different machines (in which case it isn't practical to have them poll on a "shared" array).

Comment: No, asymptotic complexity does not depend on that.

Comment: @zmbq See [this paper](http://tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/Publications2/Tight%20complexity%20bounds%20for%20parallel%20comparison%20sorting.pdf) for an example of deriving the asymptotic time complexity of a parallel algorithm using an idealized level of concurrency

Comment: @zmbq See also [this page](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~tvrdik/2/html/Section2.html) for a description of the PRAM computing model - you  appear to be using the RAM model in your criticism of my complexity analysis, but this model is not appropriate for a parallel algorithm (just like using a Turing machine model would not be appropriate for an algorithm relying on random access to memory)

Answer (score 1):

Here are ways I can think of ..

**1. Linear:** `O(n)` Total Time ~ Linear execution on a machine with single processor

**2. Parallel:** `O(n/k)` Total Time ~ Parallel execution on a machine with k processors

**3. Distributed hierarchical:** `O(m)` Time for each node in the hierarchy, O(n) Total Time; where m describe the M-ary hierarchy of processors

**4. Parallel Distributed hierarchical:** `O(1)` Time for each node in the hierarchy, `O(m^h - mh)` Total Time (which is basically number of non-leaf nodes); where h is the hierarchy height, and each node in the hierarchy has m processors

Answer (score 0):

I think you've made quite a bit of mess here. The asymptotic time complexity of notifying N subscribers is going to be at least O(N), because, well, there are N subscribers and all of them need to be notified.

You can save real-world-time by doing things in parallel (as @Zim-Zam suggested), but it won't change the asymptotic time complexity.

Same applies to the human brain, if you want to notify 5 million neurons, you won't be able to do it at once...

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a more rigorous way to describe the asymptotic complexity of a concurrent algorithm, but I've usually seen it described using an idealized level of concurrency, e.g. "this matrix multiplication algorithm runs in O(N^2) using N processes/threads/CPUs/whatever" (with O(N^3) being the single-processor/threaded/CPU/whatever complexity)

Comment: The thing about asymptotic complexity is that it is asymptotic. No matter how many processors you have, there's always a larger number when your parallelism becomes simply an improvement by a constant factor, which has no effect on the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

A hardware multicast on a network is a O(1) event publish to all the machines on the network that is listening for the multicast.  All [Ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address#Ethernet) networks support this.

There is also [IP multicast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast) that maybe closer to O(log(n) depending on the network design

> IP multicast is a technique for one-to-many and many-to-many real-time
>   communication over an IP infrastructure in a network. It scales to a
>   larger receiver population by requiring neither prior knowledge of a
>   receiver's identity nor prior knowledge of the number of receivers.
>   Multicast uses network infrastructure efficiently by requiring the
>   source to send a packet only once, even if it needs to be delivered to
>   a large number of receivers. The nodes in the network (typically
>   network switches and routers) take care of replicating the packet to
>   reach multiple receivers such that messages are sent over each link of
>   the network only once.

So if each subscriber is on a different computer it can be done, if each subscriber is on a different CPU within the same computer, it will depend on the internal design of the computer.